# PySide2 and Matplotlib: How to make MatPlotLib run in a separate Process? ..as it cannot run in a separate Thread

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiprocessing, pyside2

I am not an experienced programmer and i am trying to create a sort of datalogger program in python using Qt for python (PySide2) to build the GUI. I was able to create a gui using Designer and the load it inside python. The gui is only a blank window for now. Then i created a function that launch MatplotLib in a window showing a graph, and i updtate data in each loop of the main program, using a Qt timer.

Everithing works, but the redraw time of MatPlotLib slow down the gui refresh too much. So I tried to put MatPlotLib inside a separe Thread, and after a lot of trials i understood it cannot run in a separate Thread.. 
At the end i decided to try with Multiprocessing. Now the MatPlotLib runs fine in a separate Process ( i use queue to send data to MatPlotLib) and exit properly after the process is finished, but when i close the main window the program newer close completely, and also typing Ctrl+C the prompt is blocked.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile, QTimer

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, freeze_support
import random


class DSL(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # LOAD HMI
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        designer_file = QFile('userInterface.ui')
        designer_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader = QUiLoader()
        self.ui = loader.load(designer_file, self)
        designer_file.close()
        self.ui.show()

        # Data to be visualized
        self.data = []

    def mainLoop(self):
        self.data = []
        for i in range(10):
            self.data.append(random.randint(0, 10))

        # Send data to graph process
        queue.put(self.data)

        # LOOP repeater
        QTimer.singleShot(10, self.mainLoop)


def graphProcess(queue):
    for i in range(10):
        # Get data
        data = queue.get()

        # MatPlotLib
        plt.ion()
        plt.clf()
        plt.plot(data)
        plt.show()
        plt.pause(0.1)

    print('process end')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # MatPlotLib Process
    queue = Queue()
    freeze_support()
    p = Process(target=graphProcess, args=(queue,))
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()

    # PySide2 Process
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dsl = DSL()
    dsl.mainLoop()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using matplotlib in a secondary process it is better to embed a canvas in a QWidget that allows it to run in the same PySide2 processes:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import QFile, QObject, Signal, Slot, QTimer
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import random


class DSL(QObject):
    dataChanged = Signal(list)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # LOAD HMI
        super().__init__(parent)
        designer_file = QFile("userInterface.ui")
        if designer_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly):
            loader = QUiLoader()
            self.ui = loader.load(designer_file)
            designer_file.close()
            self.ui.show()
        # Data to be visualized
        self.data = []

    def mainLoop(self):
        self.data = []
        for i in range(10):
            self.data.append(random.randint(0, 10))
        # Send data to graph
        self.dataChanged.emit(self.data)
        # LOOP repeater
        QTimer.singleShot(10, self.mainLoop)


class MatplotlibWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        fig = Figure(figsize=(7, 5), dpi=65, facecolor=(1, 1, 1), edgecolor=(0, 0, 0))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        lay.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.line, *_ = self.ax.plot([])

    @Slot(list)
    def update_plot(self, data):
        self.line.set_data(range(len(data)), data)

        self.ax.set_xlim(0, len(data))
        self.ax.set_ylim(min(data), max(data))
        self.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dsl = DSL()
    dsl.mainLoop()

    matplotlib_widget = MatplotlibWidget()
    matplotlib_widget.show()

    dsl.dataChanged.connect(matplotlib_widget.update_plot)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi eyllanesc, thank you so much for your quick answer, it is the first time i use stackoverflow, and i'm very happy for it's help. The code you wrote works perfectly and it is a big step ahead for me. I have some question for you to undestund your choice:

Comment: - Wi was my chioce was not right for you ? (to understund my errors..)
- Is it possible to draw more lines in the graph simultaneously ( i need two)
- I used a button to show again the plot window if it is closed, using matplotlib_widget.show(), is it right ?
- why if i close the main window the grap continues to draw?

Comment: @Emilio 1) I will not indicate if it is correct or not, but as you see there is another simpler option. 2) If it is possible to draw any plot, in the following link there is an example: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/e5a2f0c86d80f4a2f241d6e3584032a9, 3) Yes, it is correct, the code must be:  `your_button.clicked.connect(matplotlib_widget.show)` 4)Try the link example with this functionality

Comment: /---------- Problem ----------/ \n Unfortunately testing deeper your code i had the same problem of my first implementation in wich the code to create the plot was simply in one function of DSL class.. If you put more, more points ( ex 1000+) the whole program slows down including the main GUI. This is because as you said both windows are in the same process. That was what i was trying to avoid whit multiprocessing. my code before trying multiprocessing was:

Comment: @Emilio The problem is your time-consuming for loop, check the updated content of the link and you will see that it does the same but is more efficient. In conclusion, analyze where the bottleneck is and there try to improve it, do not blame another part of the code.